# Embedded Linux file transfer using serial port (also used for shell)

Tags: embedded, file-transfer

I would like to transfer files between my desktop (Ubuntu) and an embedded Linux. The problem is that the only communication between the desktop and the embedded system is using the serial port. This same serial port is used to login from the desktop into the embedded system using sh (over screen or putty).

If it helps, the embedded system is the AT91SAM9G20EK running Angstrom.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to try one of the x/y/z-modem family protocols.

A free package is here:

http://ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html

And it is very likely that you also have a package for Angstrom.

To transfer a file, when connected to the embedded device you just start the program rz on the embedded linux.

Then, in the terminal on your development machine you start the zmodem protocol and send the file. Once the transfer is done, the rz program on the target machine stops, and you'll find the file in the current directory.

Comment: The idea is good, but I don't have lrzsz on the embedded system. As I cannot transfer files to the system, I cannot install anything.

Comment: Cross compile example: `CC=arm-linux-uclibc-gcc ./configure --host=arm-linux-uclibc`. Or replace the command with your toolchain command.

Answer (score 0):

You might use [PPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol) to create a TCP/IP connection over the serial link which will then allow multiple TCP/IP application layer protocols to be used simultaneously and transparently including [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol), [Telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet), [rsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Shell) or [ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_shell)

Comment: Sounds good. I'm trying it now. Had to recompile the kernel to include ppp support. At the moment this is what I see when I type pppd in the embedded systems shell: ~�}#�!}!}!} }4}"}&} } } } }%}&��5}0}'}"}(}"��~~�}#�!}!}!} }4}"}&} } } } }%}&��5}0}'}"}(}"��~~�}#�!}!}!} }4}"}&} } } } }%}&��5}0}'}"}(}"��~~�}#�!}!}!} }4}"}&} } } } }%}&��5}0}'}"}(}"��~~�}#�!}!
which is a bit uninformative for me :)

Comment: I believe that the idea is sound, and for Linux to Linux this should be straightforward-ish, however last I did anything similar it was a dial-up PPP connection between Windows NT and VxWorks, so I cannot help with Linux specifically.  However I would suggest that once you have started PPP on your *only* serial port, that port is no longer usable directly as a shell and you *have to* use a Telnet, SSH or RSH client to access the shell rather than a dumb terminal emulator.